# How to enabe NPAPI on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, websites

How can I install the plugin and enable NPAPI?

[image: How can i install the Plugin and enable NPAPI?]

1. I already download the webplugin, but still can't open and install it.
2. I went to `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi` but nothing pops out.

Answer (score 3):

Please read [this](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation).

Quoting from there:

> September 2015
>
> In September 2015 (Chrome 45) we will remove the override and NPAPI support will be permanently removed from Chrome. Installed extensions that require NPAPI plugins will no longer be able to load those plugins.

The same link also provides "Alternatives to NPAPI" which may offer some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could uninstall chrome and get the version 45 or lower.

The website http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/old